# The yogasutras 1:33 the key to peace is a inspiring verse . Can i get beautiful teachings from tantraloka of sri acharya abhinavagupta

Tags: shiva, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

I want beautiful verses which deals with compassion, peace, freindship and humanity of tantraloka in English translation and transliteration

Comment: Can you pleaae quote the verse and book here.

Comment: @ Mr Green Gold of course. Yoga Sutra 1.33 from Patanjali says:
maitri karuna muditopeksanam sukha duhkha punyapunya visayanam bhavanatas citta prasadanam
“By cultivating attitudes of friendliness toward the happy, compassion for the unhappy, delight in the virtuous, and disregard toward the wicked, the mind-stuff retains its undisturbed calmness.”